# Google Sheets Script: Reference a Chart by Name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I am trying to create a "user interface" in a sheet "Charts", that would allow them to select a Chart from a dropdown list, and it would then be displayed in just below that dropdown list.

There will eventually be numerous charts, probably on another "Chart Data" sheet, so my thoughts are to move a chart from the data sheet to the charts sheet, back and forth. Not sure if this can be done yet.

My issue is finding a way to reference a Chart in script by Name, instead of its obscure ID.

I've been all through the Chart Class etc, and don't see any way to do this. Have I missed something, or is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- From `My issue is finding a way to reference a Chart in script by Name, instead of its obscure ID.`, you want to retrieve the specific chart using the specific name.

At the sample script of this answer, the chart title is used as the specific name.

#### Sample script:

Please set the sheet name.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const chartObj = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getCharts().reduce((o, c) => Object.assign(o, {[c.getOptions().get("title")]: c}), {});
```

- By this, you can retrieve the chart object using the chart title as follows.

  - `chartObj["###chart title###"]`
- Of course, you can give other specific names instead of the chart title. In the following sample script, the specific name corresponding to the chart title is used as the key.

  ```
    const chartNames = {"sampleChartTitle": "sampleName1",,,};
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    const chartObj = ss.getSheetByName("chartSample").getCharts().reduce((o, c) => Object.assign(o, {[chartNames[c.getOptions().get("title")]]: c}), {});
  ```

  - In this case, `chartObj["sampleChartTitle"]` is the chart object for the chart title of `"sampleName1"`.

### Added 1:

From your replying, I understood that you want to retrieve all charts from all sheets in the Google Spreadsheet. For this, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const chartObj = ss.getSheets().reduce((o1, sheet) => {
  o1[sheet.getSheetName()] = sheet.getCharts().reduce((o2, c) => Object.assign(o2, {[c.getOptions().get("title")]: c}), {});
  return o1;
}, []);
```

- In this case, a chart can be retrieved by `chartObj["sheet name"]["chart title"]`.

#### Sample script 2:

When the sample script 1 is modified using the for loop, it becomes as follows. In this sample script 2 the result value is the same with the sample script 1.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheets = ss.getSheets();
const chartObj = {};
for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  const charts = sheets[i].getCharts();
  const temp = {};
  for (let j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
    const chart = charts[j];
    temp[chart.getOptions().get("title")] = chart;
  }
  chartObj[sheets[i].getSheetName()] = temp;
}
```

### Added 2:

In above script, you can retrieve the chart object by `chartObj[sheetName][chartTitle]`. But from your replying, I understood that you wanted to create a function to retrieve the chart object from the sheet name and the chart title. For this, how about the following script?

```
function sample(sheetName, chartTitle) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) return null;
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  for (let j = 0; j < charts.length; j++) {
    const chart = charts[j];
    if (chart.getOptions().get("title") == chartTitle) {
      return chart;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

- In this case, you can retrieve the chart object with `sample(sheetName, chartTitle)`.

Comment: Thanks. Are charts specific to a sheet, or to the spreadsheet? I couldn't figure this out from the Dev Docs.

Comment: @maxhugen Thank you for replying. About `Are charts specific to a sheet, or to the spreadsheet?`, at above sample script, one sheet is used. But all charts in a Google Spreadsheet can be used. So I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? About `I couldn't figure this out from the Dev Docs.`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about it. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: Just trying your code... it's a bit above my level, only been learning JS for a month, so not easy to understand. Will advise how I go. Like your idea of using the Title.

Comment: @maxhugen Thank you for replying. In the case of additional script, you can retrieve the specific chart using `chartObj["sheet name"]["chart title"]`. The reason I used `"sheet name"` as the key is that I'm worry that the same chart titles might be existing for all sheets in the Google Spreadsheet. If all chart titles are different for all charts, the script without using the sheet name can be also used.

Comment: @maxhugen I apologize for the inconvenience. Although I'm not sure whether this is help to understand the script, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit with your code. I am creating a function:  function getChartByName(sheetName,chartTitle){...} which will return a Chart object.

Comment: @maxhugen Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience again. I understood that you wanted to create a function to retrieve the chart object from the sheet name and the chart title. For this, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize again.