# Google Sheets Script: Alternatives to ROUNDDOWN() and ROUNDUP()?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm searching for an alternative to the Google Sheets functions ROUNDDOWN() and ROUNDUP() to use in GAS.  Searching for Javascript Math functions hasn't turned up any solutions.

Here's the code I'm trying to write:

```
function c_ScaleVerticalAxis(sheetName, chartTitle, rangeA1) {
// Author:  Max Hugen
// Date:    2021-08-09
// Purpose: Modify MinValue & MaxValue of Vert.Axis to suit Value Data
// Params:  rangeA1 of Values, eg "C6:C"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);
  const data = range.getValues();
  const chart = c_GetChartByTitle(sheetName, chartTitle);

  var margin = 0.1;   // a margin below/above the min/max data vals
  var decPlaces = 0;
  
  var minVal = Math.min(data);
  if (minVal > 100000)  { decPlaces = -5; } else 
  if (minVal > 10000)   { decPlaces = -4; } else
  if (minVal > 1000)    { decPlaces = -3; } else
  if (minVal > 100)     { decPlaces = -2; } else
                        { decPlaces = -1; }
  minVal = rounddown(minVal*(1-margin), decPlaces);

  var maxVal = Math.max(data);
  if (maxVal > 100000)  { decPlaces = -5; } else 
  if (maxVal > 10000)   { decPlaces = -4; } else
  if (maxVal > 1000)    { decPlaces = -3; } else
  if (maxVal > 100)     { decPlaces = -2; } else
                        { decPlaces = -1; }
  maxVal = roundup(maxVal*(1+margin), decPlaces );

  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.minValue',minVal)
    .setOption('vAxis.maxValue',maxVal)
    .build;
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}

function c_GetChartByTitle(sheetName, chartTitle) {
// Author:  Tanaike
// Link:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/64887850/190925
// Date:    circa 2020-11
// Purpose: Return a Chart object
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) return null;
  const charts = sheet.getCharts();
  for (let i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    if (chart.getOptions().get("title") == chartTitle) {
      return chart;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Are there any known alternatives, or should I try to write some custom functions to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For automatic rounding - [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

```js
Math.round(4.5) // 5
```

As an alternative to `ROUNDDOWN()` - [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

```js
Math.floor(4.89) // 4
```

As an alternative to `ROUNDUP()` - [`Math.ceil`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)

```js
Math.ceil(4.21) // 5
```

Except with these functions you can't specify how many decimal places you want, for that you would need to wrap these functions in your own custom function, here is one approach to that:

```js
function roundup(value, decimalPlaces){
    const power = 10 ** decimalPlaces
    return Math.ceil(value * power) / power
}

function rounddown(value, decimalPlaces){
    const power = 10 ** decimalPlaces
    return Math.floor(value * power) / power
}
```

Which would not require you changing the code you have above.

This code just multiplies the number you are trying to find the rounding of to 10 to the power of the number of decimal places and then uses `Math.round` or `ceil` on it, and then divides it by that same number. For example this is what the function values might look like when you are executing it.:

```
function roundup(5.23245, 3){
    const power = 10 ** 3 // 1000
    return Math.ceil(5.23245 * 1000) / 1000 // 5.232
}
```

#### EDIT:

The functions except now with error checking and accepting negative numbers

```
function roundup(value, decimalPlaces){
    if (!Number.isInteger(decimalPlaces)) throw "decimal places needs to be an integer"
    if (decimalPlaces === 0) throw "decimal places can't be 0"
    const power = 10 ** Math.abs(decimalPlaces)
    if (decimalPlaces < 0) {
        return Math.ceil(value / power) * power
    } else {
        return Math.ceil(value * power) / power
    }
}
    

function rounddown(value, decimalPlaces){
    if (!Number.isInteger(decimalPlaces)) throw "decimal places needs to be an integer"
    if (decimalPlaces === 0) throw "decimal places can't be 0"
    const power = 10 ** Math.abs(decimalPlaces)
    if (decimalPlaces < 0) {
        return Math.floor(value / power) * power
    } else {
        return Math.floor(value * power) / power
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks!  I was trying to do something with Math.ceil and Math.floor, but didn't think of your neat way of using power. :)

Comment: I think I ran into a "floating number error"?  Tried roundup(400001, -5), got 500000.00000000006. I suspect I need to use Math.round() at some point as well?

Comment: Oh, the function as is won't work with negative numbers. If you want 5 decimal places just use `5`

Comment: I edited my answer so now it accepts negative numbers too.

Comment: I think it actually does, just that floating number business.  eg roundup(390000, -5) = 400000.00000000006

Comment: With my edited function I am not getting that result, I am just getting `390000` - see screenshot attached to my answer

Comment: Math.abs() isn't working. roundup(390000, -5) should be 400000 and rounddown(390000, -5) should be 300000, as it is in Sheets itself. Your original functions do this, except for the floating error. Note that "power = 10 ** -5" = 9.999999999999999E-6 (obviously not correct).

Comment: Ahh, I see, edited final functions again, should work in the same way now, without the floating point error.

Comment: Outstanding!  I was busy going down a rabbit hole with Math.round(), haha. Many thanks for your perseverance. Cheers, Max