# GAS: Modify Chart Vertical Axis Min and Max Values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

Thanks to @iansedano for roundup() and rounddown() equivalents, and @Tanaike for past posts, I have a function that will calculate Minimum and Maximum Values for the Vertical Axis of a chart. However, there is an error when I try to Modify the chart:

`Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.updateChart`

For Modify, I used the docs example at:
[Class EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart)

The Options I found at:
[Chart configuration options](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#line-config-options)

I'm not sure, but the issue *might* be that there can be two Vertical axes, and Left or Right have to be specified somehow?

```
function test(){
  c_ScaleVerticalAxis('Chart', 'Stock SMA3', 'C6:C1263');
}
function c_ScaleVerticalAxis(sheetName, chartTitle, rangeA1) {
// Author:  Max Hugen
// Date:    2021-08-09
// Purpose: Modify MinValue & MaxValue of Vert.Axis to suit Value Data
// Params:  rangeA1 of Values, eg "C6:C"
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(rangeA1);

  // Ref: @Tanaike, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64887850/190925
  var chart = c_GetChartByTitle(sheetName, chartTitle); 

  var margin = 0.05;   // a margin below/above the min/max data vals
  var decPlaces = 0;
  
  // Ref: @Tanaike, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45203334/190925
  var ar = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], range.getValues()); 
  var minVal = Math.min.apply(null, ar);

  Logger.log('Data minVal:  ' + minVal);
  if (minVal > 100000)  { decPlaces = -5; } else 
  if (minVal > 10000)   { decPlaces = -4; } else
  if (minVal > 1000)    { decPlaces = -3; } else
  if (minVal > 100)     { decPlaces = -2; } else
                        { decPlaces = -1; }

  // Ref: @iansedano, https://stackoverflow.com/a/68710322/190925                      
  minVal = rounddown(minVal*(1-margin), decPlaces); 
  Logger.log('Chart minVal:  ' + minVal);

  var maxVal = Math.max.apply(null, ar);

  Logger.log('Data maxVal:  ' + maxVal);
  if (maxVal > 100000)  { decPlaces = -5; } else 
  if (maxVal > 10000)   { decPlaces = -4; } else
  if (maxVal > 1000)    { decPlaces = -3; } else
  if (maxVal > 100)     { decPlaces = -2; } else
                        { decPlaces = -1; }
  maxVal = roundup(maxVal*(1+margin), decPlaces );
  Logger.log('Chart maxVal:  ' + maxVal);

  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxis.minValue',minVal)
    .setOption('vAxis.maxValue',maxVal)
    .build;
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample sheet with minimum reproducible example with the complete code and your expected output?

Comment: The only code that is needed really are the last 5 lines, so you could use any chart, and change the Minimum and Maximum Values for the Vertical Index using the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `vAxis.minValue` and `vAxis.maxValue` only works for [Continuous Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous).

To set min and max vertical axis for **Discrete Charts**, use `vAxis.viewWindow.min` and `vAxis.viewWindow.max` respectively.

As stated in the configuration options.

> [image]

---

### Sample Discrete Chart (data column type of `string`)

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
function updateChart(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var newChart = chart.modify().setOption("vAxis.viewWindow.max", 20).setOption("vAxis.viewWindow.min", 5).build();
  sheet.updateChart(newChart);
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

---

### Sample Continuous Chart (data column type to one of: `number`, `date`, `datetime` or `timeofday`)

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
function updateChart1(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(sheet.getName());
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  var newChart = chart.modify().setOption("vAxis.maxValue", 30).setOption("vAxis.minValue", 0).build();
  sheet.updateChart(newChart);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ron!  FYI, the Options I used actually did work, BUT in my code I had omitted the parentheses for .build !!! Following your example revealed that.  Most appreciated, cheers Max.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)